# Differential equation with initial value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation with initial value $x(0)=-3$. I tried to solve it and came to the step which doesnt look good and I am not sure what to do next. Here are my steps:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+3x $

$\int_{}^{}\frac{dx}{x^2+3x}  \!  \, =\int_{}^{}dt \!  \,  $

$-\frac{1}{3}ln(1+\frac{3}{x} ) =t+C$

$x=\frac{3}{e^{-3(t+c)}-1 } $

$x(0)=-3$

$-3=\frac{3}{e^{-3c}-1} $

$e^{-3C}=0$

Answer (score 1):

What you have so far looks correct.

What does it imply?

$c = \infty\\
e^{-3(c+t)}=0\\
x = -3$

You have an autonomous differential equation.  That is, $x'$ depends solely on $x.$

Plug in the initial condition into the equation

$x'(0) = 0$

If $x'(0)$ then $x(\epsilon) = x(0) + \epsilon x'(0) = x(0)$

There is nothing to get this system moving.  We never get off of the initial condition.

Comment: I dont understand what excatly here is $x'$ ?

Comment: $x' = \frac {dx}{dx}$  different notations for the same thing.

Comment: But if plug x=-3 I am getting 0 in denominator?

Comment: Plug in x=-3 to the original $\frac {dx}{dt} = x^2 + 3x \implies \frac {dx}{dt} = 0$  No zeros in any denominators.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+3x$$
$$\frac{dx}{x(x+3)}=dt$$
$$\frac{dx}{3x}-\frac{dx}{3(x+3)}=dt$$

Comment: Is the solution for constant: $3C=ln(1/6)$ ?